# Copy button in Notepad program

Tags: java, swing, clipboard, jtextarea

I wonder how do I copy just the highlighted text in my notepad and not the whole of it to the clipboard.

Here's the code I wrote which copy the whole content of the `JTextArea` of my notepad:

```
private void menu_edit_copyActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(TextArea_Main.getText());
    Clipboard clpbrd = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit ().getSystemClipboard ();
    clpbrd.setContents (stringSelection, null);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `JTextArea#copy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [getSelectedText](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getSelectedText()) instead of getText

Answer (score 1):

Try [`JTextArea#copy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#copy()) instead

From the JavaDocs:

> Transfers the currently selected range in the associated text model to
>   the system clipboard, leaving the contents in the text model. The
>   current selection remains intact. Does nothing for null selections.

Answer (score 0):

The Public String getSelectedText()  should be replaced with getText() in

```
(TextArea_Main.getText())
```

This will work for you.